# Infer/omit type parameter based on usage

Tags: typescript

In Rust is possible to omit a type parameter using `_`, which infers the concrete type. Is there any way of doing the same in TypeScript? So for example, I have this now, but I want to omit the first type parameter in `open()` (see second snippet).

(This `open` is supposed to be the same as [`MatDialog.open` in Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialog))

```js
// -----
// TYPES
// -----
interface Params<T> {
  data: T;
}

function open<T, D = any>(component: ComponentType<T>, params: Params<D>) {
  // ...
}

// -----
// USAGE
// -----
interface MyComponentData {
  foo: number;
}

open<MyComponent, MyComponentData>(MyComponent, {
  data: {
    foo: 42,
  },
})
```

**The real question**, is it possible to omit `T` so it's inferred from the usage? For example, using something like `_` as placeholder (which doesn't work):

```js
open<_, MyComponentData>(MyComponent, {
  data: {
    foo: 42,
  },
})
```

Comment: Not really. TypeScript does not have partial type inference. There is a [proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for a syntax similar to what you have in your question.